# Multiple to Multiple, Junction Tables, Newbie on Database Structure

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

Please feel free to comment on this as I am new and very confused on how to structure this. 
I want to create a database of people with interests. I want to record their interests and then see what people have common interests and display them.

I have 3 tables: Person, Interest, InterestType

Person is a table of people 
Interest is an interest that a person can have. 
InterestType is the name of the interest, say Skiing or Biking. (I separated it because I want all person to use a common typeset of interests)

My setup is as follow:

personTable: id, name, interestID

interestTable: id, interestType, personID

interestType: id, name

How do I get the list of people with the same interest?

Comment: Why do you have "interestID" in the personTable? Also, there is no real need for an Id in the interestTable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a simple model in Access, but you should be able to "translate" this to SQLite without too many problems.

Given:

```
PersonTable
personId    Name
1           Paolo
2           Carla
3           Angelo
4           Franco
5           John
6           Lisa

InterestType
interestId  Name
1           Calligraphy
2           Karate
3           Chess
4           Movies
5           Hiking

InterestTable
interestId  personId
1             1
2             1
3             1
2             2
3             2
4             2
1             3
2             3
1             5
```

A simple query sorted by Interest Name and then by Person Name should do the trick:

```
SELECT interestType.Name, personTable.Name
FROM personTable INNER JOIN 
(interestType INNER JOIN interestTable ON
 interestType.interestId=interestTable.interestId) 
ON personTable.personId=interestTable.personId
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

will return:

```
interestType.Name   personTable.Name
Calligraphy            Angelo
Calligraphy            John
Calligraphy            Paolo
Chess                  Carla
Chess                  Paolo
Karate                 Angelo
Karate                 Carla
Karate                 Paolo
Movies                 Carla
```

If you want to look for a specific interest, just add a where clause:

```
SELECT interestType.Name, personTable.Name
FROM personTable INNER JOIN 
(interestType INNER JOIN interestTable ON interestType.interestId=interestTable.interestId) 
ON personTable.personId=interestTable.personId
WHERE interestType.Name="Karate"
ORDER BY 1, 2;


interestType.Name   personTable.Name
Karate                 Angelo
Karate                 Carla
Karate                 Paolo
```

Comment: Grazie (Sei Italiano?) 
I am using SQLite and I should be able to replicate this no problem.

Comment: Sì, sono Italiano. Se la risposta ti risulta utile, è "buona educazione" marcarla come "accepted" (magari aspetta un giorno così si vede se ti arrivano risposte migliori).

Comment: Perfetto. I am reconsidering the use of the interestType table. Shouldn't I be able to ask for a DISTINCT list of interest Names?
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Not knowing much of the rest of the application it is a bit difficult to add more. The interestType should work as a "dictionary" of all the available interests, so you should carefully avoid the duplication of entries due to different spellings (e.g. "Karate", "Karatedo", "KARATE", "karate" etc. - you should choose one spelling and stick to it...). Who will insert entries in this table?

Comment: interestType is a classic example of what we (Italians) call "Tabelle anagrafiche". I.e. reference tables which provide decoupling between entities and their descriptions. Please use these liberally, it makes your data base more robust to change and less prone to duplication.

Comment: The user enters the data but I have an autofill option which minimizes errors and repetitions. You suggest to decouple it then?

Comment: The database is personal and on SQLite in an mobile app. So the person can add whatever they wish. But as I mentioned before. There is a autocomplete function with dropdown suggestions as you type. This makes it much easier to pick an existing interest, therefore minimizing errors. I got it to work without the InterestType table. Using your suggestion. I think I will implement the interestType table anyways, in case one day I want to crowdsource that table and have it feed from a server instead of locally. It would be easier to plug in. Thoughts?

Comment: (I assume that the app allows someone to "tag" friends with a list of interests, then). In general it's still better to put this in a table, for various reasons based on Relational Theory and plain old experience. It also makes it easier for the user to change the name of an Interest after having added it to a few Persons. It may also help in case you want to add extra fields to an Interest, or create hierarchies of interests (meta-interests, specializations and so on). So, even if it's a small db under direct control of a single user, I'd still stick with the interestType table idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT * FROM personTable pt
 INNER JOIN interestTable it
    ON pt.id = it.id
 WHERE it.interestType = "theInterestType";
```

Comment: I will test that out. Is it even necessary for me to have the interestType table? Isn't there a way to group by the unique interest names if I used a name column instead of the interestType column?

Comment: Ah ok, now I see what you meant with the "Distinct" question. I don't think this is a good idea... as I mentioned elsewhere, the interestType should act as a reference. Instead of typing "Karate" (with all the possible alternate ways to do so) the user will be able to pick from a choice list, and the choice list will be populated from the Name field of the interestType table. So, in short: please use it to avoid duplication, mispellings and alternate versions of the same concept (interest). If you don't, whoever manages your app app will spend hours correcting "wrong" entries.

Comment: @Sam Casil Thank your for your suggestion. It was correct. I had to modify it a bit to fit my needs. Good advice!!